# How aggregate data by "group by" hour from datetime python DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a pandas dataFrame composed of several columns, each columns were merged by the key datetime. My columns datetime has this shape : 
time = "day-month-year hour".

I'm looking for how aggregate and take the mean of each value of each hour of each day.

1) Does something simple like groupby.(hour) exist ?

2) If I apply :

```
prevs = prevs.groupby('time').mean()
```

Does this function "group by"  take the smaller granularity (hour in my case) ?

Here is an exemple of my code for dat/time format:

```
prev = pd.read_csv('....csv',sep = ";")
prev = prev.drop(['cloud_cover', 'date', 'humidity', 'latitude_r', 'longitude_r', 'pressure', 'wind', 'wind_dir'],axis=1).dropna()
prev['time'] = prev['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
prev['time'] = prev['time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H'))
prev.columns = ['temperature_weatherbit','time']
```

Comment: Only a comment because I am unsure to correctly understand your question. 1/ pandas as a notion of period of time that can be used in `groupby` *provided the time are true `Timestamp` or `Period` and not strings. 2/ prevs.groupby('time') will have the granularity of the `time` column.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, in fact, by using prevs.groupby("time") the action "group by" works for smallest granularity automatically (by hours in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question but a way to do this is by creating a new column with the granularity you want. For instance, if you want to group them by hour, you could do something like the following.

```
df['hour'] = df.time.dt.hour
df.groupby(by=["hour"]).your_column.mean()
```